# How can I add patterns to my ggplot2 graph that relate to my "fill" groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a unique pattern across all of my "splt" categories on my `ggplot2` graph, but I do not have much experience and need some help doing this. I am trying to get "hexagons", "crosshatch", "right45", and "checkerboard" for splits 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively. **I would also like to keep the color patterns from the original bar chart.**

Here is the dataset and code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
library(magick)
library(tidyverse)

## Data to work with
data <- structure(list(trt = c("t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t3", "t3", "t3", "t3", "t4", "t4", "t4", "t4"), splt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), response = c(82, 62, 17, 93, 55, 99, 42, 67, 56, 8, 62, 69, 38, 80, 86, 26), standard_error = c(2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4), hsd = c("abcdef", "abcdef", "abcdefg", "abcdefg", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh", "abcdefgh",  "abcdefgh")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

fun <- function(string, dist = 3){
  left <- substr(string, 1, dist)
  right <- substr(string, dist+1, nchar(string))
  paste0(left, "\n", right)
}

# Change to factor
data$splt <- as.factor(data$splt)

ggplot(data, aes(fill = splt, x = trt, y = response))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), col = "black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = response, ymax = response + standard_error), 
                width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(
    pattern= 'magick',
    width= 1, 
    stat= "identity", 
    fill= 'white', 
    colour= 'black',
    pattern_scale= 3,
    pattern_aspect_ratio= 1,
    pattern_key_scale_factor= 1.5
  )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Splt"))+
  xlab("Treatment")+
  ylab('Response')+
  ggtitle("Title",
          subtitle = "Subtitle")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 11),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'cm'))+
  geom_text(aes(label = fun(hsd), y = response + standard_error, group = splt), vjust = -0.9, 
            size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))+
  ylim(0, 118)+
  scale_pattern_type_manual(values = c(`1` = 'hexagons', `2` = 'crosshatch',
                                       `3` = 'right45', `4` = 'checkerboard'))
```

The result of this code can be seen in the following image, which is not correct:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `facet_grid` you can get it to work.  Try this and tweak as necessary.

```
mycolor <- c("red", "green", "blue", "purple")

ggplot(data, aes(fill = splt, x = splt, y = response))+
  facet_grid(. ~ trt) +
  # geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), col = "black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = response, ymax = response + standard_error), 
                width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.8))    +
  geom_bar_pattern(
    pattern=  'magick',
    aes(pattern_type = splt, pattern_fill = splt),
    width= 1, 
    stat= "identity", 
    # fill= 'white', 
    # colour= 'black',
    pattern_scale= 1,
    pattern_aspect_ratio= 1,
    pattern_key_scale_factor= 1.2
  )    +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=mycolor)) ) +
  xlab("Treatment")+
  ylab('Response')+
  ggtitle("Title",
          subtitle = "Subtitle")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 11),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'cm'))+
  geom_text(aes(label = fun(hsd), y = response + standard_error, group = splt), vjust = -0.9, 
            size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))+
  ylim(0, 118)+
  scale_pattern_type_manual(values = c('hexagonal', 'crosshatch',
                                       'right45', 'checkerboard'))
```

[image: output]